# Alguém poderia me ajudar a identificar o erro? 1179 Preenchimento de Vetor IV -URI

Tags: python

[image: 1179 URI]

Então pessoal, estou estudando Python durante as ferias da faculdade e me deparei com este problema no URI.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ainda sou iniciante na linguagem, e em programação de modo geral. Alguém poderia me dizer o motivo pelo qual a plataforma não aceita meu código? Tentei seguir tudo à risca, mas não entendo o por que do site não aceitar o código quando submetido. 
Meu código abaixo:

```
pares= []
impares= []

for i in range(15):

    n= int(input())
    if n%2==0:
        pares.append(n)

    if n%2!=0:
        impares.append(n)

a=0 

for i in pares[0:5]:
    print('par[{}] = {}'.format(a, i))
    a+=1

b=0

for i in impares[0:5]:
    print('impar[{}] = {}'.format(b, i))
    b+=1

if len(impares)>5:

    c=0
    for i in impares[5:]:
        print('impar[{}] = {}'.format(c, i))
        c+=1

if len(pares)>5:

    d=0
    for i in pares[5:]:
        print('par[{}] = {}'.format(d, i))
        d+=1
```

Se alguém puder me ajudar serei grato.

Comment: O que quer dizer "***a plataforma não aceita meu código***" ? Pois o resultado é o mesmo que na imagem!

Comment: Quando submeto à plataforma, me retorna a mensagem "Wrong answer (40%)". Sim, o resultado é o mesmo da imagem, e por isso não entendo o motivo do código não ser aceito. Acredito que a lógica não esteja errada -e caso veja algo que demonstre o contrário, por favor!rs fique a vontade para me dizer- então vou tentar outras maneiras de obter a mesma saída pedida no problema.

Answer (score 1):

A questão aqui prende-se com um pormenor no enunciado, este:

> Só que o tamanho de cada um dos dois vetores é de 5 posições. Então, cada vez que um dos dois vetores encher, você deverá imprimir todo o vetor e utilizá-lo novamente para os próximos números que forem lidos

Repare que você não está a fazer isto. Primeiro está a guardar tudo e só no fim é que mostra em blocos de 5. Já para não falar que mostra de 0 a 5 e depois de 5 para a frente, o que significa que se receber 15 pares como entrada mostra de 0 a 5 e depois de 5 a 15 o que está errado.

Pode testar com esta entrada que vê o erro:

```
10
20
30
40
50
-10
-20
-30
-40
-50
12
14
16
18
20
```

Resultado VS Esperado:

```
par[0] = 10    VS    par[0] = 10
par[1] = 20    VS    par[1] = 20
par[2] = 30    VS    par[2] = 30
par[3] = 40    VS    par[3] = 40
par[4] = 50    VS    par[4] = 50
par[0] = -10   VS    par[0] = -10
par[1] = -20   VS    par[1] = -20
par[2] = -30   VS    par[2] = -30
par[3] = -40   VS    par[3] = -40
par[4] = -50   VS    par[4] = -50
par[5] = 12    VS    par[0] = 12
par[6] = 14    VS    par[1] = 14
par[7] = 16    VS    par[2] = 16
par[8] = 18    VS    par[3] = 18
par[9] = 20    VS    par[4] = 20
```

Repare que as posições dos últimos 5 pares estão diferentes, pois os últimos 10 são escritos num só `for`.

A solução é até mais simples que o código que tem. Basta criar uma função para mostrar o array com um determinado texto, o `par` ou `impar`, e cada vez que chega a 5 elementos você mostra e limpa o array:

```
def mostra_array(array, texto):
    for posicao, num in enumerate(array):
        print("{}[{}] = {}".format(texto, posicao, num))

pares= []
impares= []

for i in range(15):
    n= int(input())
    if n%2==0:
        pares.append(n)
        if len(pares) == 5:  # mal chega aos 5 mostra e limpa
            mostra_array(pares, "par")
            pares = []

    if n%2!=0:
        impares.append(n)
        if len(impares) == 5: # mal chega aos 5 mostra e limpa
            mostra_array(impares, "impar")
            impares = []

# no fim os que sobraram são escritos, começando pelo impar
mostra_array(impares, "impar")
mostra_array(pares, "par")
```

[Veja esta solução a correr com o teste que coloquei acima no Ideone](https://ideone.com/a8JvKr)